# Create a view where every line comes from a different table

Tags: mysql, select, view, count, mysql-workbench

I have tables for multiple `stations` with data from each station: `timestamp`, `error` etc. The total number of rows in each table is the frequency of errors at that station. The name of the station is in the table name.

```
CREATE TABLE Station_00 (error INT, timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO Station_00 VALUES (1, '2020/10/05 12-12-12'),(2,'2020/10/05 12-12-15'),(3,'2020/10/05 12-12-20'),(4,'2020/10/05 12-12-25'),(5,'2020/10/05 12-12-30'),(6,'2020/10/05 12-12-35'),(7,'2020/10/05 12-12-37'),(8,'2020/10/05 12-12-40');

CREATE TABLE Station_01 (error INT, timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO Station_01 VALUES (1, '2020/10/05 12-14-12'),(2,'2020/10/05 12-14-15'),(3,'2020/10/05 12-14-20'),(4,'2020/10/05 12-14-25');

CREATE TABLE Station_02 (error INT, timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO Station_02 VALUES (1, '2020/10/05 12-14-17'),(2,'2020/10/05 12-14-20'),(3,'2020/10/05 12-14-26'),(4,'2020/10/05 12-14-29'),(5,'2020/10/07 12-14-29');

CREATE TABLE Station_03 (error INT, timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO Station_03 VALUES (1, '2020/10/05 12-17-12'),(2,'2020/10/05 12-17-15'),(3,'2020/10/07 12-14-20'),(4,'2020/10/07 12-14-25'),(5,'2020/10/07 12-14-30'),(6,'2020/10/07 12-16-25');
```

Event values are random, not necessarily in ascending order like here.

I want to create a `VIEW` with as many rows as there are stations and columns `station` (the name of each table) and `frequency` (the number of rows in each table). Is there any way to do that in one `SELECT` ?

I would like something like:

```
+---------+-----------+
| Station | Frequency |
+---------+-----------+
|      00 |         8 |
|      01 |         4 |
|      02 |         5 |
|      03 |         6 |
+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: You may use UNION ALL, of course. But separate subquery for each separate table needed. Think about structure normalizing (one table for all stations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `union all`:

```
create view myview as
select '00' as station, count(*) as cnt from table_station00
union all select '01', count(*) from table_station01
union all select '02', count(*) from table_station02
```

Note, however, that all these tables should probably be consolidated in a single table, with an additional column that represents the station. Then, you could just do:

```
select station, count(*) cnt from table_station;
```